# Use read() to get the name of a file from a pipe and open() it in c

Tags: c, linux, pipe

This is all done on a linux machine.

I have a pipe, fp, sending from the parent to the child the name of a file using a buffer.

The buffer is:

```
char buf[20];
```

the child has the following code:

```
{
//we are in the child
    close(fp[1]);
    int fd;
    read(fp[0],buf,20);
    if((fd=(open(buf, O_RDONLY)))==-1) exit(1);
    else exit(0);
    close(fp[0]);
}
```

Even if I type in the name of a file that exists, I'm getting the exit status of 1. So...
this unfortunately doesn't work. The issue is that the buff itself not only does '\n', but also also plenty of '\0', all of which don't actually exist in the name of real file. I've tried replacing the '\n' with a '\0' but that also doesn't work. How can I solve this?

Here's the whole code.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
 
 
int main(){
    int fp[2];
 
    if (pipe(fp) < 0){
        printf("error creating pipe\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
 
    int id;
    char buf[20];
 
    id=fork();
 
    //father process here --------------------------------
 
    if (id!=0){
        close(fp[0]);   //closing read
 
        printf("program name: ");
        fflush(stdout);
        read(STDIN_FILENO,buf,20);
        write(fp[1],buf,20);
 
        int waitstatus, exitcode;
 
        wait(&waitstatus);
 
        //check if exited correctly
        if (WIFEXITED(waitstatus))
            exitcode = WEXITSTATUS(waitstatus);
        else
        {
            printf("Bad exit\n");
            return 0;
        }
        if (exitcode==1) printf("error, file doesn't exist\n");
        else printf("file does exist\n");
 
        close(fp[1]);
    }
 
 
 
 
    //child process here --------------------
    else{
        close(fp[1]); //closing write
        int fd;
        read(fp[0],buf,20);
        //write(STDOUT_FILENO, buf, 20);
        if((fd=(open(buf, O_RDONLY)))==-1) exit(1);
        exit(0);
        close(fp[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: `20` seems to be very short for a file name.

Comment: You should share the father side where you write the filename in the pipe.

Comment: pafi[1] is weird here, should be fp[1]. Anyway, you write 20 bytes in the pipe on the father side, so you get 20 bytes on the other side in the child. That is why you get garbage at the end of the file name. You should write only the filename which is supposed to be <= 20 in size. So, you must terminate the filename with an '\0' and write strlen(filename) + 1 to get a complete string on the other size.

Comment: when you read from stdin, store the result of read() to know how many chars you have read. Then use this value to put a terminating '\0' at the end of buf (overwrite the read '\n').

Comment: @RachidK. doesn't strlen read '\n'? read() also reads '\n', so I've had to replace '\n' in the buffer to '\0', but with that addition, your solution worked.

Comment: @Maridiama, yes of course. strlen() stops at the first encountered '\0': this is the string terminator. That Is why I told you to replace '\n' by '\0'. But you can also do the same without using strlen(): rc = read(STDIN_FILENO,buf,20); buf[rc-1]='\0'; write(fp[1],buf,rc);

Answer (score 1):

You send the full `buf` which contains a newline and other indeterminate values. You need to remove the newline and I suggest that you only send what you need on the receiving end.

```c
printf("program name: ");
fflush(stdout);
if(fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin)==NULL) return 1;
size_t len = strlen(buf);
buf[len - 1] = '\0';      // remove the newline
write(fp[1], buf, len);   // only send what you actually need
```